# Make job run at end of all others with HTC condor

Tags: condor

I have a dag file for HTC condor with a few hundred jobs. I want to add one more job/node to the dag, but with the condition that it should run after all the others are done. I have tried doing setting it as the child of all jobs, but if one of the other jobs fail this job doesn't run.

Is there a way to make this job run at the end, but without caring about the success or failure of other jobs?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: my solution is: this is not possible. There is currently no way for condor to allow you to run something after all jobs in a batch are complete. thank you

Answer (score 1):

For the parent nodes that have jobs that could possibly fail, you could add a POST script that always succeeds (returns exit code 0). This marks the node successful and the DAG will continue executing.

See this part of the manual for more info http://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor/manual/current/2_10DAGMan_Applications.html#SECTION003102400000000000000